# Serialize/deserialize via super class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Suppose I have 1 base class and a derived class.
The derived class has extra fields that the base class doesn't.

I then instantiate the derived class and assign it to a definition of the base class.
What happens when I serialize and deserialize the object via the base class.

For example:

```
Class TypeA{
   int var1;
}

Class TypeB extends class TypeA{
   int var2;
}

Class X{
  public TypeA obj = new TypeB();
}
```

If I now serialise  "obj" does var2 get included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, serialization doesn't depend on the type of the reference (which `obj` actually is, a reference I mean) but on the type/class of the object being referenced, which is still `TypeB`. If you call `obj.getClass()` it will return `TypeB.class` and that's what serialization will see as well.

Comment: You could serialize, deserialize and then cast `obj` to `TypeB` to prove that right.